# Elmah and Web Deploy - Error Log Clears After Each Deployment

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

Everytime I publish my MVC 3 project from Visual Studio, the log files for Elmah get overwritten.  Is there a way to prvent this from happening?  I already tried excluding my app_data folder from being published and it didn't have any effect.